# No audio while using my custom SIP app between FSClient and Android phone

Tags: android, sip, freeswitch

I have Freeswitch server configured, am able to make audio calls between two FSClient instances successfully. However, if I use the same two numbers to connect a VOIP call between a FSClient instance and an Android phone, the call is received and answered but there is no audio. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong on Android. My code is pasted below.

Appreciate any help you can provide.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public SipManager mSipManager = null;
private SipProfile mSipProfile = null;
public SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
private final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

private class IncomingAudioCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final Context appContext = context;

        try {
            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, android.net.sip.SipProfile caller) {
                    try {

                        Toast.makeText(appContext, "Incoming Call Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        incomingCall = call;
                        incomingCall.answerCall(30);
                        incomingCall.startAudio();
                        incomingCall.setSpeakerMode(true);
                        if(incomingCall.isMuted()) {
                            incomingCall.toggleMute();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // Call picked UI
                    Toast.makeText(appContext, "Call is On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // Call ended. Back to normal UI
                }
            };

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

            incomingCall = mSipManager.takeAudioCall(intent, null);
            incomingCall.setListener(listener, true);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (incomingCall != null) {
                incomingCall.close();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.TestVoip.INCOMING_CALL");
    IncomingAudioCallReceiver callReceiver = new IncomingAudioCallReceiver();
    registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);

    Button btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            instantiateSip();
        }
    });

    Button btnCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testCall);
    btnCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            initialiseCall();
        }
    });

    Button btnDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect);
    btnDisconnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                mSipManager.close(mSipProfile.getUriString());
            } catch (SipException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    Button btnAnswerCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerCall);
    btnAnswerCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer Incoming", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                incomingCall.answerCall(200);
                incomingCall.startAudio();
                incomingCall.setSpeakerMode(true);
                if(incomingCall.isMuted())
                    incomingCall.toggleMute();
            } catch (SipException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void instantiateSip()
{
    try {
        if(mSipManager == null) {
            mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
        }

        EditText txtUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        EditText txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(txtUserName.getText().toString(), "14.49.56.12");
        builder.setPassword(txtPassword.getText().toString());
        builder.setPort(5060);
        builder.setProtocol("TCP");

        mSipProfile = builder.build();

        SipRegistrationListener regnListener = new SipRegistrationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                    String errorMessage) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration failed.  Please check settings.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registering with SIP Server...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        };

        System.out.println(mSipProfile.getUriString());

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.TestVoip.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        //mSipManager.register(mSipProfile, 200, regnListener);

        mSipManager.open(mSipProfile, pendingIntent, null);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opened Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        /*
        if (mSipManager.isRegistered(mSipProfile.getUriString()))
        {
            mSipManager.open(mSipProfile);
        }
        else
        {
            mSipManager.register(mSipProfile, 200, regnListener);
        }
        */

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SipException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void initialiseCall()
{
    try {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, android.net.sip.SipProfile caller) {
                try {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

               @Override
               public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {

                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answered Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                  call.startAudio();
                  call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                  call.toggleMute();
               }

               @Override
               public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                  // Do something.
                   super.onCallEnded(call);
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ended Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
               }
            };

            EditText txtNumberToCall = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberToCall);

        SipAudioCall call = mSipManager.makeAudioCall(
                mSipProfile.getUriString(), "sip:" + txtNumberToCall.getText().toString() + "@14.49.56.12", listener, 30);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (SipException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception :" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Permissions set<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.software.sip" android:required="true" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.software.sip.voip" android:required="true" />

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer ! As per documentation, startAudio() requires two permissions to be set, which I had not. Once I added them, I started to get the audio at both ends.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```